# Find double summation

Tags: polynomials, summation, roots-of-unity, symmetric-polynomials

If $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \dots, \alpha_{100}$ are all the 100th root of unity,  then what is the numerical value of ${\displaystyle\sum\displaystyle\sum}_{1\leq i<j\leq 100} (\alpha_i\alpha_j) ^5$?

**added** 
We have
${\displaystyle\sum\displaystyle\sum}_{1\leq i<j\leq 100} (\alpha_i\alpha_j) ^5={\displaystyle\sum\displaystyle\sum}_{1\leq i<j\leq 100} \alpha_i^5\alpha_j^5$.  I don't know what to do now.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\alpha^{100}=1$, we see that our sum equal to $0$

because by the Viete's theorem $$\sum_{i=1}^{100}\alpha_i=\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq100}a_ia_j=...=\sum_{1\leq i_1<i_2<...<i_{10}\leq100}a_{i_1}a_{i_2}...a_{i_{10}}=0$$

Comment: It is indeed $0$, but shouldn't you say that it's $\frac{1}{2} ( (\sum_k \alpha_k^5)^2 - \sum_k \alpha_k^{10} ) $   ?

Comment: @orangeskid Yes of course and we still get $0$.

Comment: Well, I guess they just depend on the sums $s_l$ with $1\le l \le 10$ so indeed, $0$.